# Fastest way to create 1000 folders one inside another and put a file in the last folder

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu, hierarchy

I've written a code for searching a specific file , where the user enters a `starting path` and a `filename` , and then the program prints its details if the file exists , or prints `not found` otherwise.

The code is based on recursion . I want to test it with a large folder hierarchy , let's say 1000 folders , one inside the other , and put a file called `david.txt` inside the 1000th folder .

How can I do that without creating 1000 times folders for the next 3 hours ?

The code is written in `C` , under `Ubuntu` .

Thanks

Comment: @ErickWong: Indeed: `python -c 'print "tst/" * 1000' | xargs mkdir -p`

Comment: You'll need to keep the folder name short - Linux supports paths up to 4096 characters.  I'm not sure how well things will/won't work once you get past that mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following in your shell:

```
mkdir -p folder$( seq -s "/folder" 999 )1000
```

Then you can enter this folder:

```
cd folder$( seq -s "/folder" 999 )1000
```

and create a file:

```
touch david.txt
```

and come back to your previous dir:

```
cd -
```

Comment: Thanks ,but the output for the `1st` command is : `a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ mkdir -p folder$( seq -s "/folder" -t 1000 999 )
seq: invalid option -- 't'
Try seq --help' for more information.`

Comment: @ron - then probably "seq" in your distribution does not support `-t` argument. Use the updated version

Comment: I'll do that - thanks . BTW , how can I access the `1000th` folder ,for creating the file ?  since after entering the `2nd` command you wrote I got `File name too long` . 10x again!

Comment: @ron - see my comment to your question - you'll need to keep the folder names short to avoid going over Linux's pathname size limit.

Answer (score 2):

As some comments described, I would use the shell for such purposes:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(seq 1000)
do
    mkdir tst
    cd tst
done
touch david.txt
```

On a related topic, let me suggest [this article](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/12/more-shell-less-egg), which shows how sometimes shell scripting can solve your problems in much less development time.  Specially for *ad-hoc* problems like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple bash loop:

```
$ pushd .
$ for i in {1..1000}; do
      mkdir d$i;
      cd d$i;
  done

$ touch david.txt
$ popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code, (almost), to create the folders and files.  Once that is working, the searching/reporting is almost done as well.  It's sorta self-testing :)